# How to reference a secret properly in AWS codebuild as environment variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

When I reference a secret in codebuild as environmen variable, I use

[image]

But when referring to the password:

I get the following error in the build:

- minimum field size of 32, GetSecretValueInput.VersionId.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. For me I removed the below part of resource policy of secrete, and then the error is gone.

```
{
"Effect" : "Deny",
"Principal" : {
  "AWS" : "*"
},
"Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
"Resource" : "*",
"Condition" : {
  "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals" : {
    "aws:PrincipalArn" : [  
          "arn:aws:iam::98765321:root", 
          "arn:aws:iam::12345678:root", ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why that works. I looks like a bug for me